# How can I import & export modules in Node.js where I have the module names and directories as strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

My folder structure looks like this:

```
modules
    module-and
        index.js
    module-not
        index.js
    module-or
        index.js
    module-xor
        index.js
    moduleBundler.js
```

The file I'm working in, `moduleBundler.js`, imports the modules from each module folder / file, then exports them all as one bundle:

```js
import ModuleAnd from "./module-and";
import ModuleNot from "./module-not";
import ModuleOr from "./module-or";
import ModuleXor from "./module-xor";
export { ModuleAnd, ModuleNot, ModuleOr, ModuleXor };
```

How can I make this code automatically import and export each of these modules, without needing to hardcode their names and directories within `moduleBundler.js`?

I'm able to get the names and directories of each of the modules with this code:

```js
const moduleDirectories = getDirectories(__dirname);
const moduleNames = moduleDirectories.map(x => x.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + camelise(x).slice(1));


console.log(moduleDirectories);
>>> [ 'module-and', 'module-not', 'module-or', 'module-xor' ]

console.log(moduleNames);
>>> [ 'ModuleAnd', 'ModuleNot', 'ModuleOr', 'ModuleXor' ]
```

But there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of importing or exporting modules using these values.

I tried looping over each folder and importing them like this:

```js
for (const i in moduleNames) {
    import moduleNames[i] from ("./" + moduleDirectories[i]);
}

>>> ReferenceError: from is not defined
```

I also tried using `eval()`, knowing its security risks, just to see if it would work:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(moduleNames)) {
    const directory = "./" + moduleDirectories[parseInt(key)];
    eval(`import ${value} from "${directory}"`);
}

>>> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I know for `eval()` I could *maybe* get it working by adding `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`, but I'd rather avoid doing that if possible. I'd rather avoid `eval()` entirely, too, if possible.

Also, once I have got them imported, how can I then export them as a bundle?

Comment: You don't. Best you can get is to auto-generate the `moduleBundle.js` file itself as a build step.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Turns out I needed to use `require` instead of `import`, d'oh!

Using the arrays `moduleDirectories` and `moduleNames` which I created earlier:

```js
for (const i in moduleDirectories) {
    const directory = "./" + moduleDirectories[i];
    module.exports[moduleNames[i]] = require(directory).default;
}
```